# Find when rubygems were installed

Tags: rubygems

Following the recently hacking of http://rubygems.org/, I wanted to check when gems installed on my system were installed; is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

'gem help install' at the end will show you the default installation directory on your machine.  If you have always used the default, you should be able to go to that directory's 'gems' sub-directory and find all of your gems.  In addition, there is also a 'cache' directory at the same level.

One more thing.  You can then run the "stat" command against any such gem.